# Negative abnormal stock return and permanent impact

Tags: equities, time-series, statistics, event-study, abnormal-returns

Assume we have a day where stock price falls many standard deviations of the mean (e.g >3) . How could we test, in terms of time-series, if this negative shock is permanent or deminishes in the long run(e.g 1 year).

One example, would be testing the impact of a physical disaster on a stock, component of a sensitive to these phenomenon sector.

Comment: This is a classic econometrics question. It is discussed here:(https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/14350/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transitory-and-a-permanent-shock) for example.